# Как красиво сделать?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Здравствуйте помогите ! Как можно красиво вывести новости на сайте !

Ну вот есть новости в базе

```
id:1,name:'Что то',content:'Бооольшой текст'
id:2,name:'Что то',content:'Бооольшой текст'
id:3,name:'Что то',content:'Бооольшой текст'
```

Я вызвал страницу новости через `XMLHttpRequest()`!
А теперь вопрос что дальше ?

Как собрать все новости в JSON PHP и отдать их Javascript ?

И вывести все эти новости в `<div id="content"></div>`

Использую Javascript без библиотеки jQuery !

Comment: В JSON его и MySQL может собрать, если 5.7.8 или старшее...

Comment: А вывести как ?

Comment: ну, один из способов выглядит так: `for (let news of newsArray) { newsDiv.innerHTML += \`<div><h2>${news.name}</h2><div>${news.content}</div></div>\`; }`

Comment: Реакт, только реакт!